# Get closest previous date

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

I need to get the posts closest to a date.

```
SELECT id
     , datetime
  FROM dates
 WHERE id != 150003
   AND datetime > FROM_UNIXTIME(1549622615)
 ORDER BY datetime
 LIMIT 1
```

Returns a correct result:

```
{"id":"150015","datetime":"2019-04-13 17:47:55"}]
```

but when I change to "datetime < FROM_UNIXTIME(1549622615)" I get the result:

```
{"id":"1","datetime":"1970-01-10 12:06:07"}
```

when there are many posts closer to the datetime.

Any insights why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change it to `datetime < FROM_UNIXTIME(1549622615)` you also need to change the sort order to `ORDER BY datetime DESC` to get the closest date.